# recursion method not returning a string

Tags: java, palindrome

I have to create a code that can find the longest palindrome contained inside sentences. (eg. Some people like cake but I prefer pie; the longest palindrome is i prefer pi). The problem is that upon running the code it doesn't return the palindrome. I'm not sure what the problem is but if anyone can figure it out I'd appreciate you letting me know. Thanks!

Code is below...

```
public class Recursion6 {
    
    static String recursion(String word, int currentLength, int x, String substring) {
        String reverse =new StringBuffer(word).reverse().toString();
        if(word.length() == 1 ){
            return substring;
        }
        if(word.charAt(0) != word.charAt(x)) {
            if(x == word.length() - 1) {
                recursion(word.substring(1), currentLength, 1, substring);
            }
            x++;
            recursion(word, currentLength, x, substring);
        } else {
            if(word.substring(0, x + 1).equalsIgnoreCase(reverse.substring(word.length() - (x+1), word.length()))) {
                if(word.substring(0, x).length() > currentLength) {
                    currentLength = word.substring(0, x + 1).length();
                    substring = word.substring(0, x + 1);
                    
                }
                recursion(word.substring(1), currentLength, 1, substring);
            }
            recursion(word.substring(1), currentLength, 1, substring);
        }
        return substring;
    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a Sentence:");
    String word=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("The Palendrome is "+recursion(word.replaceAll(" ", ""), 1, 1, null));        
    sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Longest palindromic substring, is that what you are asking?

Comment: the longest plaindrome is contained in the substring variable. The idea was that when the program was finished searching the sentence it would return substring and print it. I tried to do this with if(word.length() == 1) but it doesnt return anything

Comment: Same issue as in this question: [Recursive method returning empty value](//stackoverflow.com/q/59820574), maybe you learn something from  the answers there and can fix your program then.

Answer (score 0):

You ignore the return value.

For example:

```
       recursion(word, currentLength, x, substring);
```

There's a return value, all right. You just do nothing with it for the recursive calls.  What gets returned from the outermost call is just the input to the outermost call, which is a null string.

You probably need to review how recursive activation works. The 'return' statement only returns from the current level, it does not empty the entire call stack.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach.

- First, just get all the substrings on the stack.  That's what the first two recursive calls do.
- Then just check each substring as the stack unwinds to see if it is a palindrome.
- the private method does the actual check. It simply compares characters at both ends towards the middle.
- Final output may contain white space and/or punctuation characters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String s = 
        "Some people like radar, others " +
        "like a man, a plan, a canal, panama!, but " +  
        "my favorite is 'I prefer pie'";

String res = findLongestPalindrome(s,0,s.length());
System.out.printf("'%s'%n", res);
```

prints

```
' a man, a plan, a canal, panama!, '
```

The method takes the string, and starting and ending indices.

```
public static String findLongestPalindrome(String s, int start, int end) {
    String save = "";
    if (end - start > 0) {
        save = findLongestPalindrome(s, start + 1, end);
    } else if (end > 1) {
        save = findLongestPalindrome(s, 0, end - 1);
    }
    String temp;
    if (isPalindrome(temp = s.substring(start, end))) {
        if (temp.length() > save.length()) {
            save = temp;
        }
    }
    return save;
}
    
// iterates from the ends toward the middle.
    
private static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    s = s.replaceAll("\\W+", "").toLowerCase();
    int end = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() >> 1; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(--end)) {
            return false; // fast fail if any two are not equal
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```